# Is offering the contents of a third party web site offline violating the law?

Tags: web-crawler, offline-files, scraping

I have developed a nice little app that crawls a bunch of newspaper web sites and makes their latest content available on my phone offline. It's basically a Pocket app that saves contents automatically, once a day. I am wondering: if I ever wanted to put my app online, would I be infringing any laws?

Comment: iam not a lawyer, but it already exist rss feed app that do like your app want to do. (like that one; https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/free-rss-reader/id290537970?mt=8)

Comment: **All** legal questions are [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on [SF]. Ask your lawyer and not the internet.